# Disable TCP checksum offloading on KVM virtual network

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu, ethtool

I have a virtual network for connecting KVM guests with the host.

I need to disable TCP checksum offloading on this network. The ethtool works fine but I want to disable it **permanently** and I could not find anything in virsh or QEMU documentation. Adding /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-virbr1 file with the corresponding options also does not work.

Comment: You want to disable offloading on a _virtual_ network?!

Comment: The client on the virtual guest is connecting to the server running on its virtual host. When the tx checksum offloading of the host virtual network is on the client receives packets with wrong checksum. When I turn off the offloading the problem disappears.

Comment: @jackhab Weird problem. How did you notice it? I'm just curious.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin well, I noticed HTTP requests are stuck so I looked at the traffic in Wireshark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ethtool -K eth0 tso off` in `rc.local` or the vm startup script. You could probably do it as a [libvirt hook](http://libvirt.org/hooks.html) too

Answer (score 3):

I recommend doing this with a udev rule. I put this in /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bridge.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", NAME=="virbr*", RUN+="/sbin/ethtool -K $env{INTERFACE} tx off"
```

More sophisticated approaches are possible, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it in the guest's interface xml:

```
<driver>
      <host csum='off'/>
      <guest csum='off'/>
    </driver>
```

Refer to https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#setting-nic-driver-specific-options

Answer (score 1):

I generally used this:

```
<interface type='network'>
    <model type='virtio'/>
    <driver name='vhost'>
        <guest csum='off' tso4='off' tso6='off'/>
    </driver>
</interface>
```

it seems to now trigger a syntax error, YMMV. The difference, as far as I can tell, is that this way it's disabled on the guest side of the split-/paravirtual driver.

Looking at https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-16.07/sample_app_ug/vhost.html it seems that 'vhost' is only existing if you have the DPDK enabled.